# How to hide a row in kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = " Grid with Multicolumn headers";
}

@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@using SampleUIApp.Areas.GridSample.Models
@model SampleUIApp.Areas.GridSample.Models.GridSampleModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Grid Sample - InLine Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PageLayout.cshtml";
}

@section pageBody {


                   <div style="float:right;margin-right:10px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px">

                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("Hide_toolbar")
                    .Events(e => e.Click("Hidetoolbar"))
                    .Content("Hide Toolbar"))

                       @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("Show_toolbar")
                    .Events(e => e.Click("Showtoolbar"))
                    .Content("Show Toolbar"))

                    </div>
    <br />
    <br />

    @using (Html.BeginForm("InLineIndex", "GridSample", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "InLineIndexMain" }))
    {


        <div id="DetailPanel" class="containerDiv100">
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridSampleModel>()

                .Name("KendoGrid1")  // Grid Name can be used in Javascript, if required.

                //Columns defination of the fields.
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Template(m => m.SampleId).Title("<input id='checkAll', type='checkbox', class='check-box' />");
                    columns.Group(group=>group
                        .Title("Personal Information")
                        .Columns(info => {
                            info.Bound(m => m.SampleName).Title("Sample Name").Width(200).Filterable(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:x-small" });
                            info.Bound(m => m.Age).Title("Age").Width(100).Filterable(false).Format("{0:d}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:right" });
                            info.Bound(m => m.Height).Title("Height").Width(150).Locked().Filterable(false).Format("{0:N2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:x-small" });
                            info.Bound(m => m.City).Title("City (Auto Complete)").Width(350).Lockable(false).Filterable(true).ClientTemplate("#=City.CityName#");

                        })
                    );

                    //columns.Bound(m => m.Age).Title("Age").Width(100).Filterable(false).Format("{0:d}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:right" });
                    //columns.Bound(m => m.Height).Title("Height").Width(150).Locked().Filterable(false).Format("{0:N2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:x-small" });
                    //columns.Bound(m => m.City).Title("City (Auto Complete)").Width(350).Lockable(false).Filterable(true).ClientTemplate("#=City.CityName#");

                    columns.Bound(m => m.Category).Title("Category (Drop Down List)").Width(400).Filterable(true).ClientTemplate("#=Category.CategoryName#");
                    columns.Bound(m => m.EmployeeList).Title("Employee (Multi Select)").Width(300).Filterable(true).ClientTemplate("#= renderSelectedEmployees(data.EmployeeList)#")
                        .EditorTemplateName("ClientEmployee");


                    columns.Bound(m => m.EntityStatus).Title("Status (CheckBox)").Width(200);

                    columns.Bound(m => m.CreditCard).Title("Credit Card No (Masked TextBox)").Width(250).HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "font-size:x-small" });
                    columns.Bound(m => m.StartDate).Title("Start Date ").Width(150).Filterable(false).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:x-small" });
                    columns.Bound(m => m.EndDate).Title("End Date").Width(150).Filterable(false).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:x-small" });
                    columns.Bound(m => m.Qty).Title("Quantity").Width(100).ClientTemplate("#=Qty#").HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "text-align:right" });
                    columns.Bound(m => m.Rate).Title("Rate").Width(100).ClientTemplate("#=Rate#").Format("{0:N2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "text-align:right" });

                    columns.Bound(m => m.LineValue).Title("Value").Width(100).Format("{0:n2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "text-align:right;" });


                    columns.Command(commands =>
                    {
                        commands.Edit().Text(" ");
                        commands.Destroy().Text(" ");
                        commands.Custom("Hide").Click("Hide").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "min-width : 0;font-size:x-small;" });
                    }).Title("Commands").Width(200).HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:x-small" });
                })
                .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                {
                    toolbar.Custom().Text("Add New Sample").Name("add").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Toolbar_right" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:x-small" }).Url("~/GridSample/GridSample02/Create");

                    toolbar.Create().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Toolbar_right" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "hide-button" });
                })

                .Editable(editable => editable.Enabled(@Model.EditEnable).Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))  // will make grid editable with all cells
            // Here "Enabled(@Model.EditEnable)" will allow user to edit the grid control or not depending on Model's EditEnable value i.e. True / False

                .Pageable()  // Display grid data in multiple pages depending on PageSize parameter
                .Scrollable(config => config.Enabled(true)) // Make grid Scrollable
                .Filterable(config => config.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu)) // Allow to set filters on different columns of the grid
                .Sortable() // Allow user to sort the data in grid
                .ColumnMenu() // Display menu with different actions on

                // Display grid row in different colour it will be helpful to identify which grid row is selected.
                .Selectable(selectable => selectable
                .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple)
                .Type(GridSelectionType.Row))

                .Navigatable()
                .Resizable(config => { config.Columns(true); })
                .Reorderable(config => { config.Columns(true); })
                .Events(events => events.Save("OnCellDataModified").Edit("OnCellChange")) // Grid events to call javascripts on different actions.
                .DataSource(source => source
                    .Ajax()
                    .Batch(false)
                    .PageSize(5)
                    .ServerOperation(false)
                    .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(m => m.SampleId);
                        model.Field(m => m.Category).DefaultValue(
                            ViewData["defaultCategory"] as CategoryViewModel);
                        model.Field(m => m.City).DefaultValue(
                            ViewData["defaultCity"] as CityViewModel);

                        //Given below code will not allow user
                        //to change (either manual / calculated) the given cell value
                        //But it will also do not change updated value in model

                        //model.Field(m => m.LineValue).Editable(false);
                    })
                    // Actions called from controller
                    .Read(read => read.Action("Fetch", "GridSample", new { area = "GridSample" }))
                    .Create(create => create.Action("InLine_Insert", "GridSample", new { area = "GridSample" }))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("InLine_Update", "GridSample", new { area = "GridSample" }))
                    .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("Delete", "GridSample", new { area = "GridSample" }))

                    )
            )

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Code added for Keyboard Navigation Support
            $(document.body).keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 87) {
                    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").table.focus();
                }

            });

            function OnSelectEmply(e) {
                // This sample javascript function called from Employee MultiSelect Partial View
            }

            function CalculateTotValue(data) {
                return data.Qty * data.Rate;
            }

            function OnCellChange(e) {
                //alert("Cell Change");

                //Disable the edit mode depending on the model value of EntityStatus field i.e. True / False
                $("#LineValue").prop("disabled", e.model.EntityStatus);

                //Set Default values while adding new row in Grid
                if (e.model.isNew() && !e.model.dirty) {
                    e.container
                        .find("input[name=SampleName]") // get the input element for the field
                        .val("Sample Name - 4") // set the value

                        .change();   // trigger change in order to notify the model binding
                }
            }

            function OnCellDataModified(e) {
                //alert("Cell Data Modified");

                if (e.values && e.values.LineValue) {
                    //alert("Calculate # LineValue");
                    var qty = e.values.Qty || e.model.Qty;
                    var rate = e.values.Rate || e.model.Rate;
                    e.model.set("LineValue", rate * qty);
                    e.values.set("LineValue", rate * qty);

                    $("#KendoGrid1").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
                }
                else {
                    if (e.values && (e.values.Qty || e.values.Rate)) {
                        //alert("Calculate # Qty, Rate");
                        var qty = e.values.Qty || e.model.Qty;
                        var rate = e.values.Rate || e.model.Rate;
                        e.model.set("LineValue", rate * qty);
                        e.values.set("LineValue", rate * qty);

                        $("#KendoGrid1").data("kendoGrid").refresh();

                    }
                }
            }

            function renderSelectedEmployees(List) {
                //alert(List.length);
                if (List != undefined && List[0] != undefined) {
                    var text;
                    $.each(List, function (index) {
                        if (text == undefined)
                            text = List[index].EmployeeName;
                        else
                            text = text + ", " + List[index].EmployeeName;
                    })

                    //alert($("#LineValue").width);
                    if (text.length > 30) {
                        text = text.substring(0, 5) + " .... (" + List.length.toString().trim() + ")"
                    }
                    return text;
                }
                else
                    return "";
            }
            function Hide(e)
            {

                var grid = $("#KendoGrid1").data("kendoGrid");
                ////e.preventDefault();
                //var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                //var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                //var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);

                //grid.tbody.find("tr:first").hide(); 
                grid.tbody.closest("tr").Hide();
                //grid.tbody.closest("tr").hide();

                //var item = this.dataSource.get(); //Get by ID or any other preferred method
                //this.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + item.uid + "']").hide();


            }
            function Hidetoolbar() {



                $(".k-grid-add").hide();

            }
            function Showtoolbar() {



                $(".k-grid-add").show();

            }
            $("#kendoGrid1").on("click", ".hide-button", function () {
                alert("reached");
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
            });
        </script>
    }
}
```

As you can see there is custom command button know as hide in my grid.. i wish to hide the row when that button is clicked..
how do i get hat done?
i have tried a line as                 grid.tbody.find("tr:first").hide(); 
but this works only for the first line. wha should i do for the other rows?

Comment: The task is formed of two parts. First part is to get the actual row index. Do you already have  way of getting the row number of the button upon click? The second part is to actually make the row invisible. This should look like grid.tbody.find("tr.eq(" + yourIndex + ")").hide(). If you give me more information, I can post a nice answer.

Comment: i do have a method to get row number.. please tell me how to do that.. and what more info should i provide you with? @LajosArpad

Comment: For starters, I would like to know how you defined the click event. The only open question before I can post an answer for you is: how can you get the value denoted as yourIndex in my previous comment? I cannot tell you how unless I get more information.

Comment: function Hide(e) {

                var grid = $("#KendoGrid1").data("kendoGrid");
                 
                grid.tbody.find("tr:first").hide(); 
                
                 

            }
This is how i am doing it.. i do not know how to get the row index 
@LajosArpad

Comment: How do you use the Hide function?

Comment: I believe you have defined a click handler for those buttons. I need to know more about the click handlers.

Comment: if you see my code i have it there is my column.command
columns.Command(commands =>commands.custom.....


@LajosArpad

Comment: Can you give me a fiddle link if you have for this kind of function.. or just give me a method of finding the index of the row on which the button is clicked
@LajosArpad

Comment: Read my answer, it might help you.

Comment: i did read.. but it didnt help.. 
i edittted my qstn.. i added the complete html page @LajosArpad

Comment: You still have this in your code: commands.Custom("Hide").Click("Hide").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "min-width : 0;font-size:x-small;" });. I told you to not use that Click event. I told you to not define styles on your server. You have given the hide-button class to the toolbar and not to Hide. You pasted Javascript, but you did not paste the HTML. You did not follow the steps I have described, so you cannot determine whether my solution works. You did not give me the HTML. Right click on your browser, view source and copy the relevant part, which is the grid. Paste it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector will find only the first `tr`, so only the first line.

You need to change your selecor to:

```
 grid.tbody.closest("tr").hide();
```

Comment: thats what i am asking.. how should i make it happen for each row on which the button is located.. @Magicprog.fr

Answer (score 0):

This code is very ugly:

```
commands.Custom("Hide").Click("Hide").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "min-width : 0;font-size:x-small;" });
```

It is mixing server-side code with css and javascript. Forget about the click event and do not give it style attribute. You should give it a class attribute. Let's name its class `hide-button`.

Define a rule for your hide-button elements in CSS, like this:

```
.hide-button {
    min-width: 0;
    font-size: x-small;
}
```

Make sure that this CSS rule is loaded in your page.

Then, your Javascript should be defined. Since you have not given us the HTML the code generated, I will assume your HTML contains a grid, which contains a tbody, which contains tr elements, which contain td elements. One of the td elements will contain your `hide-button` in each row. So, you should define this behavior:

```
$("body").on("click", ".hide-button", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

Note, that since you did not give me enough information, I have used assumptions in my answer. As a result, if any of my assumptions was wrong, the answer will not work for you. If you have any more problems, then make sure that you give me all the information.